# Stata and how to use local variables on a regression

Tags: variables, regression, stata, local

I have 2 sets of variables which explain an outcome (motor and size) and I am interested in finding which part of the predicted outcome belongs to which set. `local motor` could contain 1 or more variables. In order to do this I want a code which understands which variables are in `motor` and adds their impact in a single variable called `predict_motor_smart`. In this example `predict_motor_smart` should be equal to `predict_motor`. In essence I need to find an expression for the last line of code which is robust to a change in specification of `local motor` variables.

```
sysuse auto, clear

local outcome "price"

local  motor "mpg rep78"

local  size "weight length"

regress `outcome' `motor' `size'

gen predict_motor = _b[_cons] + mpg * _b[mpg] + rep78*_b[rep78]

 * gen predict_motor_smart = _b[_cons] + var1  of motor * beta 1 of motor + var2 of motor * beta2 of motor
```

Comment: Please find your CAPS LOCK key and turn it off, so you'll stop SHOUTING at us. Just like everywhere else on the web, typing in ALL CAPS is considered to be very impolite. SHOUTING will not get you help any faster, and it's rather inappropriate to SHOUT when you're asking us for *free help* to solve *your problem*. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. Never heard before that writing in all caps is considered to be impolite, but I am not writing that much in posts so you must be right.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you just need to use `predict` after `regress'.  No need to use local macros (always called that in Stata, not local variables). m

Comment: Thank you Nick. Predict would work for the total prediction of the outcome, but I need to also differentiate between the part of the predictio cuased by motor and the part of the prediction caused by size.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sysuse auto, clear
 local outcome "price"
 local  motor "mpg rep78"
 local  size "weight length"
 regress `outcome' `motor' `size'
 predict outcome_predict
 gen predict_motor = .
 replace predict_motor = _b[_cons] + mpg * _b[mpg] + rep78*_b[rep78] if 
 outcome_predict!=.
 gen predict_motor_smart =.
 replace predict_motor_smart   = _b[_cons] if outcome_predict!=.
 foreach l of local circumstances{
 replace predict_motor_smart  = predict_motor_smart  +`l'*_b[`l']
   }
```